# To use ?> or php?>

Tags: php

the tech guy at one of my clients raised to me I wasn't using `<?php` everywhere and would need to change that because of security reasons. Fair point, will do my good sir! However, he also asked if I could change `?>` to `php?>` as the closing tags and that seemed a bit odd to me. I have never seen that, nor any mention of it anywhere (Google gave me a total of 0 relevant results). And even my code editor implies that that is faulty code.

Can anyone enlighten me if it even exists and if so what benefits it offers above ?>

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ALWAYS `<?php` then is can never fail when `short_open_tag` are turned off

Comment: `php?>` is not a closing tag ever as far as I know

Comment: @RiggsFolly I think it's `short_open_tag`

Comment: Beware of experts. Lots of people like the title, a lot more than deserve it

Comment: @AlonEitan You are right, I can never remember that one without looking it up

Comment: He/she really "Tech guy" your client had? or i'm too young to know old school version, who knows?

Comment: I just had a thought! If you are using some templating or other tool in PHP then it is just possible that the tool requires the `php?>` tag to terminate itself and drop you back into raw PHP. But I dont know of one, but then I am not an expert!

Comment: When coding and obeying the [PSR-2](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/#files) coding standard, closing tags must be omitted in files containing only PHP

Comment: I am using it in combination with HTML so I do actually have to close the file with it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
echo "echo   ";
php?>
```

The output is:

```
echo
Notice: Use of undefined constant php - assumed 'php' in /tmp/test.php on line 4
```

In `php?>`, the `php` part is not a component of the "end of PHP code" marker. It is just a constant that you haven't defined just like in `junk?>`.

Answer (score 3):

The [PHP tags docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php) clearly says that `<?php` is an opening tag and `?>` is closing tag.

You can use short opening tag `<?` but you need to enable [short_open_tag](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) in your `php.ini` file first.

However in some cases it's good to omit the closing tag.

> If a file is pure PHP code, it is preferable to omit the PHP closing tag at the end of the file. This prevents accidental whitespace or new lines being added after the PHP closing tag, which may cause unwanted effects because PHP will start output buffering when there is no intention from the programmer to send any output at that point in the script.